# Egorov's theorem for this Lebesgue integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to prove Egorov's theorem using this Lebesgue integral defined by the upper integral
$$\int^*f:=\left\{\int h ; h \ge f \text{ and h upper-continuous }\right\}$$

$$\int_*f:=\left\{\int h ; h \le f \text{ and h lower-continuous }\right\}$$

So a Lebesgue integral of a function $ f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ exists $\int f \Leftrightarrow \int^*f = \int_*f$.

I am also allowed to use the following theorems:

- $L^p$ is a Banach space;
- Dominated convergence theorem;
- Monotone convergence theorem;
- $C^{\infty}$ is dense in the Lebesgue-functions.

But the huge problem is: We don't know what Borel-sets are and we don't have anything like measures so far. Therefore, all standard proofs of this theorem are not applicable to this situation. Hence, I wanted to find out whether anybody here knows a way how to do it?

Maybe I should say more about how this integral is defined:

Every semincontinuous function is the limit of a monotone sequence of continuous functions with finite support $g_n$. The integral over these kind of functions is defined via n-times 1 dimensional integration over all variables and then $\int h:= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int g_n$. (But this is probably not that relevant to this proof).

If anything is unclear, please let me know

Comment: How do you state Egorov's theorem without referring to a measure?

Comment: The measure of a set is just defined as $\mu(A):= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} 1_A(x)dx$

Comment: Still, could you write explicitely the statement that you want to prove? Usually, Egorov involves *measurable* functions...

Comment: Yes, so it stays the same, cause a function in this case is called measurable iff the following integral exists( integral from above and below coincide) and we have that $|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f | < \infty$

Comment: The integral in your definition of measure $\mu$ is the Riemann-integral? If yes, then the sufficient and  necessary condition of R-integrability gives the description of those sets $A$ for which you can define $\mu$. After that you should verify that $\mu$ is a measure at all.

Comment: no it is the Lebesgue integral defined in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

There is a book by Klaus Bichteler titled "Integration - A functional
approach," which has a proof of Egoroff's theorem using this approach. A set $E$ is called
integrable if its characteristic function $\chi_{E}$ is integrable.

If a sequence of integrable functions $f_{n}$ converges a.e. on an integrable
set $E$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is an integrable set
$F\subseteq E$, with $\int\chi_{E\setminus F}\leq\varepsilon$, such that
$\{f_{n}\}_{n}$ converges uniformly on $F$. Given natural numbers $m,n,r$ the
sets
$$
E_{m,n}^{r}:=E\cap\{|f_{n}-f_{m}|>1/r\}
$$
are integrable, and so is the set
$$
G_{p}^{r}:=\bigcup_{m,n\geq p}E_{m,n}^{r}=E\cap\bigcup_{m,n\geq p}
\{|f_{n}-f_{m}|>1/r\}.
$$
Moreover, $G_{p+1}^{r}\subseteq G_{p}^{r}$ and $\bigcap_{p=1}^{\infty}
G_{p}^{r}$ is contained in the set of points in which $\{f_{n}\}_{n}$ does not
converge. It follows by the monotone convergence theorem that
$$
\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}\int\chi_{E\setminus G_{p}^{r}}=\int\chi
_{E\setminus\bigcap_{p=1}^{\infty}G_{p}^{r}}=\int\chi_{E},
$$
which implies that
$$
\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}\int\chi_{G_{p}^{r}}=0.
$$
Thus, for every $r\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $p_{r}$ such that
$$
\int\chi_{G_{p_{r}}^{r}}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{r}}.
$$
Set
$$
G:=\bigcup_{r=1}^{\infty}G_{p_{r}}^{r},\quad F:=E\setminus G.
$$
Then
$$
\int\chi_{E\setminus F}=\int\chi_{G}\leq\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\int\chi_{G_{p_{r}
}^{r}}\leq\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{r}}\leq\varepsilon.
$$
Note that if $x\notin G$, then $\{f_{n}(x)\}_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in
$\mathbb{R}$, so we always have pointwise convergence in $F$. It remains to
prove that $\{f_{n}\}_{n}$ converges uniformly on $F$. Given $\eta>0$ let $r$
be such that $\frac{1}{r}<\eta$. If $x\in F$ and $m,n\geq p_{r}$, then
$x\notin G_{p_{r}}^{r}$, that is,
$$
|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\leq\frac{1}{r}<\eta.
$$
Letting $m\rightarrow\infty$ we get
$$
|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\leq\eta
$$
for all $x\in F$ and all $n\geq p_{r}$, which gives uniform convergence.

This version of Egoroff's theorem is for integrable functions. The book also
gives a version for measurable functions. Given an integrable set $E$, a
real-valued function is measurable on $E$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there
is an integrable set $F\subseteq E$, with $\int\chi_{E\setminus F}
\leq\varepsilon$, such that $f$ is the uniform limit of elementary functions
in $F$. A function is measurable if it is measurable on every integrable set. You can find more details in the book.